# Tungle.me type calendar scheduling component

Tags: ajax, jquery-plugins, jquery, javascript

Is there any component for group calendar scheduling just like tungle.me

Anyone can come and pick up a date from the calendar, the calendar would be bound to a database.

Are there any plugins available in JQuery or any other libraries?

Otherwise, can you help me design such calendar?

Thanks.